# Python Dataframe new columns from dictionary

Tags: python, dictionary, dataframe

I have a dictionary called pair_candidates. It is the co integration of various stocks. When I run:

```
for key, value in pair_candidates.iteritems():
    print key
    for i, x in value.iteritems():
        print i
        print x
```

yields:

```
GOOG
Equity(26578 [GOOG_L])
0.99474625176
Equity(46631 [GOOG])
1.0
NEM
Equity(154 [AEM])
0.986407479901
Equity(5261 [NEM])
1.0
USB
Equity(25006 [JPM])
0.976828428881
Equity(25010 [USB])
1.0
CMA
Equity(1620 [CMA])
1.0
Equity(8399 [ZION])
0.982642475515
Equity(25006 [JPM])
0.980413261534
AMAT
Equity(337 [AMAT])
1.0
Equity(7671 [TXN])
0.978239746926
Equity(8677 [MCHP])
0.978793774219
```

What I would like is a dataframe as follows please:
[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/Ly0Am.png)

Comment: Do you use `pandas` or `r` ? Can you give your dict to question?

Comment: If `pandas` do you try `df = pd.DataFrame(pair_candidates)` ?

Answer (score 0):

as far as i try to understand your point, your dataset should looks like this isnt it?

```
data = {}
data['key1'] = {'s1' : 123, 's2' : 1234}
data['key2'] = {'s3' : 123, 's4' : 1234}
```

where if i try your code to print it :

```
for key,value in data.items():
    print(key)
    for i,x in value.items():
        print(i)
        print(x)
```

i get output very similliar to what you've described

```
key1
s1
123
s2
1234
key2
s3
123
s4
1234
```

if yes, u can just do :

```
import pandas as pd
print(pd.DataFrame(data).T)
```

the output will be

```
     s1      s2     s3      s4
key1  123.0  1234.0    NaN     NaN
key2    NaN     NaN  123.0  1234.0
```

Answer (score 0):

One request to you, please also post sample data. 
I have solved your problem assuming the following format

```
pair_candidates = {'GOOG':
             {
                 'Equity(26578 [GOOG_L])':0.99474625176,
                 'Equity(46631 [GOOG])':1.0
             }
         }
```

Now to add this dictionary to a dataframe,

```
import pandas as pd

indexes = []
for k,v in pair_candidates.iteritems():
    indexes.append(k)

df = pd.DataFrame(index=indexes)

for key, value in pair_candidates.iteritems():
    for sub_dict_key, sub_dict_value in value.iteritems():
        df.ix[key,sub_dict_key] = sub_dict_value
```

The output that I'm getting is :

```
df
      Equity(46631 [GOOG])  Equity(26578 [GOOG_L])
GOOG                   1.0                0.994746
```

I hope this is the solution you wanted